# SQL, update all values trimming the start

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column `type` in my Postgresql db with a lot of values like `Content::News` or `Content::Video`.

I need to strip `Content::` for every value in the column

Can I use?

```
select ltrim(type, 'Content::')
```

Comment: The code looks correct. What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `replace`:

```
select replace(type, 'Content::', '')
```